# React app completely empty, and still can't get bootstrap to work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap

Solved: I installed bootstrap in the wrong directory (outside the main project).

This is literally everything I did so far:

```
npx create-react-app bootstraptest
cd bootstraptest
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
npm start
```

I checked, bootsrap was installed, I can see it packag.json, package-lock.json and its modules are present in node_modules, everything seems to be working fine so far.

Then I then added this to App.js:

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
```

No errors, then the second I add a bootstrap Button to test:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        
        <Button>test</Button>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The page turns white, completely blank, occasionally I get huge error walls of text that start with "dispatcher is null". Then I refresh and the page turns white again. If I try to inspect it, nothing is rendered inside react HTML's div whose id="root".

Why is this happening, what steps did I miss when setting up Bootstrap? I see that what I did is enough for it to function for most people yet it doesn't in my case.

The second I use the  I get 3 errors in the console:

One in react.development.js:209 :

Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Another in react.development.js:1618 :
Uncaught TypeError: dispatcher is null

And another in react-dom.development.js:18687 :
The above error occurred in the  component: ../node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Button.js/Button<@localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:40509:7

Also I have the latest versions; Because I just installed both and created the react app:
"bootstrap": "^5.2.3", "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4"

This is package.json inside bootstraptest:

```
{
  "name": "boot",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is package.json in the same level as bootstraptest:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: No I did that, I got the default react page with the rotating logo and everything.

Comment: Your JSX is invalid, it should be `<Button>test</Button>`. This is just a **typo** ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-resonance-vwk0kr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Just a typo, I changed it and the page is still blank

Comment: Blank pages usually have errors in the console. Can you see any? Also, what versions of each library (react, react-bootstrap and bootstrap) do you have installed (check the versions in `package.json`)

Comment: Instead of posting the …, post the entire contents of App.js, it can’t be that big and it’s very relevant, along with the package.json

Comment: Err, are you saying you have two `package.json` files?

Comment: yes, running npm install bootstrap react-bootstrap added "node_modules" folder, "package.json" and "package-lock.json" outside my bootstraptest folder, that could be the problem, I'll try merging them with the other files/folders with the same name inside bootstraptest and see.

Comment: It really sounds like you skipped that step I mentioned in my first comment (now deleted). After running `npx create-react-app bootstraptest`, the very first thing you need to do is run `cd bootstraptest`. You cannot install extra dependencies until you do that. Running `npm` commands should be done with the `bootstraptest` directory as your current working directory. You can run `pwd` to verify

Comment: @Phil That was indeed the problem, it seems like I skipped the change directory command and installed bootstrap in the wrong directory, which I didn't know could cause problems before, thank you so much.